# Running external python test from SoapUI

Tags: selenium, soapui

I am running a external selenium test from soapui with the following code below:

```
def cmdArray2 = ["python", "C:/Users/Desktop/SOAPProject/Test.py"] 
def process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray2).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
process.inputStream.eachLine {
    log.warn(it)
}
process.waitFor()
return process.exitValue()
```

When the test fails it gives the error on the log, however, it passes the soap test. I would like the test to be failed if there is an error with the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `return process.exitValue()` to `assert process.exitValue() == 0`. This assumes that your python script returns correct exit values.